# Layers section is not in the render settings panel?

Tags: rendering, render-layers

I'm very new to Blender and I have been watching some tutorials on how to make models within it. In every one of these, their render settings (In the properties tab) have a *Layers* section below the *Performance* section.

My version of blender does not seem to have that, at least by default. I've looked around the user preferences and haven't found anything. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Could you link to a tutorial which has this? Is it possible you could you be thinking of the *Layers* section in the [*Renderlayers*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render/Post_Process/Layers) panel? ([screenshot](http://pasteall.org/pic/65760))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that you are mixing two different tabs of the *Properties editor* into one.
The *Performance* section is in *Render* tab of the *Properties editor* (camera icon), see image below:

[image: Scene tab]

The *Layers* and *Passes* sections (which are needed for compositing) are in the *Render Layers* tab (small pictures icon, second from left), see image:

[image: Render Layers tab]

Check out this [BlendFile](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/26474). Note that there are two *render Layers* (A and B).

Both have scene layers 1, 2 and 10 enabled in *Scene layer* selection.

In *Render Selection*, "RenderLayer-A" has layers 1 and 10 enabled, and 
"RenderLayerB" has layers 2 and 10 enabled.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The render layers where moved into their own section within properties starting with 2.67 - there are many older tutorials available that still show the render layers within the render settings panel.

Current Render Layers

[image]

Previous Render Layers (2.66)

[image]