# All layers are not rendering

Tags: rendering, render-layers

I have a scene set up with several layers. Everything is lit correctly and, when I change the shading mode to rendered, everything's just great. The moment I actually render the image though, only one layer shows up. Is there a control panel for setting the layers to render?

Comment: see if [this answer helps](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/6532/5113)

Comment: Worked great! Somehow all of my layers got turned off.